# How to get the child of a game object via script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

[image: The script is attached to the Pistol]

How would I get access to the WeaponDescription via a Script attached to the Pistol gameObject.

NOTE:
WeaponDescription is a Text and I want to be able to change the text in the script.

Comment: On the duplicated question, read from where it says **"Finding scripts/components attached to child GameObject:"**

Comment: transform.FindChild("WeaponDescription")